# Clearing the accumulator before loading values from a variable

Tags: assembly, subtraction, mano-machine

I have been working on writing a program that does this:

```
Suppose we have the following program:
  DF1 = A - B
  SUM = DF1 + C
  DF1 = 1
  SUM = SUM + DF1 + C
Write a (Mano) assembly program that does what the pseudo-code program does.  
Assume that each variable is translated to a labelled memory address.
```

I believe it is correct for the most part, but unfortunately there is not a very reliable mano assembly compiler out there to test my code. Anyways, my only concern is where I have the *CLA* instruction at line 17. I did this to set DF1 to zero because we want to load a fresh value in there of *1*. Would this be the correct thing to do?

If anyone has any other critiques or suggestions on errors or improvements that I might have missed please provide your input.

Any and all help/input is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
ORG 100   /Program loaded into address 100 (hex)
CLA       /Clear accumulator....DF1 = 0
STA DF1   /Save DF1
LDA DF1   /Load current DF1
LDA B       /Load B to accumulator
CMA       /Create 2's complement
INC
ADD A       /Subtract B from A  
STA DF1   /Save DFI

LDA SUM   /Load current SUM
ADD DF1   /Add DF1 to SUM
ADD C       /Add C to SUM
STA SUM   /Save SUM

CLA       /Clear accumulator....DF1 = 0 
LDA DF1   /Load current DF1
ADD 1       /Add 1 to DF1
STA DF1   /Save DF1

ADD SUM   /Add SUM to DF1
ADD C       /Add C to DF1
STA SUM   /Save SUM 

DF1 -
SUM -
A   -
B   -
C   -
```

Comment: please dont use links in your questions...

Comment: I just added the code to the posting and not in a link.

Comment: one of the links not both...